# textViewDidBeginEditing: within UIWebView not being called

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextview, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

i´ve created a subclass from UIView and put in a UIWebView. This displays a simple external website which contains just two textfields. The user can type in his email address and the verification.

I´ve already included the UIWebViewDelegate for the webViewDidFinishLoad: method. Additionally i´ve created a NSNotification for "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification".

Everything works, but when i select the second textfield, the first textfield automatically will be scrolled half out of the visible area. I´ve also included the UITextViewDelegate with **- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField** but i get no NSLog from that delegate method.

Any help how i can get the frame of the selected textfield (within a UIWebView)?
Thanks for any hints...

Answer (score 0):

I´ve read that there are no UITextField delegates when using UIWebView. So therefore no information about which textfield is currently selected, right?